# Server headers, referrers, etc

Tags: php, javascript, http-headers

I have a script, called javascript.php, witch I include in my SCRIPT tag in my html, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.php"></script>
```

What I would like to know, is it possible under the javascript.php to check if someone directly accessed it, like:

```
http://myhost.com/javascript.php
```

And if someone included it in his HTML?

More precisely: Is there a header witch server recieves from the client if he requested it directly via URL, or via the SCRIPT request under the HTML sources?

Comment: Don't bother.  Firebug will defeat that trivially.

Answer (score 3):

No, there won't be anything guaranteed with that.

Comment: He is right. There is a referer header but it can be manipulated easyly.

Comment: I need to know if it's included as a script in HTML or if it's directly accessed, nothing more :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

but this sent from user agent which mean they can send anything they would like to

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution which MAY decrease "silly" attempts to include your script:

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'])){
    $parts = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']);
    $allowed_hosts = array('example.com');

    if(!in_array($parts['host'], $allowed_hosts)) {
        exit;
    }
}
```

As guys mentioned above, referrer header could be manipulated easyly. If you want really prevent this issue, you can add to the script path some GET-parameters which are generated using simple rule, and then check them. For example:

**index.php**

```
$c1 = rand();
$c2 = md5($c1.'HAHA');
$codes = '?c1='.$c1.'&c2='.$c2;
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.php<?php echo $codes; ?>"></script>
```

**script.php**

```
if(!isset($_GET['c1']) || !isset($_GET['c2']) || md5($_GET['c1'].'HAHA') != $_GET['c2']) {
    exit;
}
...
```

The lack of this solution is that your JS-file will not be cached by browser, because it will called with different parameters everytime.